# How to make menu expand towards up to accommodate newly added entries

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

As shown below in the images, I have a menu and I want to add entries or items to that menu. The restriction I have is to maintain the position of the lower-left corner of the menu. In other words, I want every time an entry is
added the menu should expand in height "the upper-left corner" and the lower-left corner remains the same.
The idea is no matter the number of entries added the menu should expand to accommodate the newly added entries so that the two buttons in image_1 are always appearing not to get hidden by the menu.
Please have a look at the css code posted below and please let me know how to modify it to achieve the aforementioned requirements.

**CSS**:

```
#select-site-layers-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top:800px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 15px;

    display: block;
    width: 305px;
    height: 200;

    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: .15rem;
    background-color: white;

    z-index: 2; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

**img_1**:

[image]

**img_2**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know you want the bottom of the menu to be at 800px from the top instead of specifying the top distance you can specify the bottom as:

```
bottom: calc(100% - 800px);
```

The 100% here refers to the height of the containing element which is body in your example.

Here's an example snippet. Remove an item and see that the list shrinks from the top not the bottom. Add an item and it will expand upwards as required.

```css
body {
  background: cyan;
  height: 1000px;
}

#select-site-layers-overlay{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% - 800px);
  right: 0px;
  padding: 15px;

  display: block;
  width: 305px;
  height: 200;

  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: .15rem;
  background-color: white;

  z-index: 2; 
  cursor: pointer;
  
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="select-site-layers-overlay">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```